# asp.net MVC login user still route to login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner of ASP.NET MVC and want to create a login page in an ASP.NET MVC application. 
I have a database on a server and a dll which checks if user name and password are valid or not. 
My problem is after completed log-in the application still routes to the login page, not home page and I don't know what should I do.

This is my code:

login page

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    string url = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +
                     Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
    Services.UserLogin login = new Services.UserLogin(url, model.UserName, model.Password);
    bool result = login.IsValidLogin();
    if (result)
    {
       return Redirect(url + "/" + "Home/Index");
    }
    else
    {
       return View(model);
    }
}
```

Assume this is my `login.IsValidLogin()` method and it always return true:

```
bool IsValidLogin()
{
    return true;
}
```

so I want if `login.IsValidLogin()` is true to redirect to the home controller.

My home controller

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

i change this in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I don't know the next step. Should I create a flag that I have a valid user or not 
I have no idea.

Should I deal with OWIN middleware?

Comment: Are you using `[Authorize]` in your `HomeController`

Comment: yes [Authorize] is added 
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the authentification cookies after validate the user login infos :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return View(model);
    }
    string url = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +
                     Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
    Services.UserLogin login = new Services.UserLogin(url, model.UserName, model.Password);
    bool result = login.IsValidLogin();
    if (result)
    {
       // Set authentification cookie
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
       return Redirect(url + "/" + "Home/Index");
    }
    else
    {
       return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: the same problem when i debug its go first to void Dispose(bool disposing) in account controller which have signInManager ... i ignore the _signInManager in login method